# Get the integral part of a BigFraction, as a BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger, fractions, apache-commons-math

What is an easy way to get the integral part of a `BigFraction` as a `BigInteger`?

Basically I want the same result that the `intValue` and `longValue` methods return but with arbitrary precision.

I also want to avoid rounding so indirect conversion via a `BigDecimal` is not suitable.

Comment: I need the BigFraction Object, but can't find the jar files online. where do you get it? thx.

Comment: @SecureFish, http://commons.apache.org/math/download_math.cgi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myBigFraction.getNumerator().divide( myBigFraction.getDemoninator() );
```

?

Comment: Unsurprisingly `BigFraction.longValue()` is implemented this way.  The surprising part is that there is no `bigIntegerValue()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
BigFraction fraction = ...

BigInteger num = fraction.getNumerator();
BigInteger den = fraction.getDenominator();
BigInteger[] divideAndReminder = num.divideAndRemainder(den);
```

Then finally

```
BigInteger integralPart = divideAndReminder[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
bigInteger = bigFraction.genNumerator().divide(bigFraction.getDenominator());
```